# Precisely Why Does uname -m Report the Wrong Architecture When Run By Sun Grid Engine (SGE)?

Tags: linux, architecture, debian, sungridengine, uname

I have 64-bit Debian Squeeze systems that run an older 32-bit version of SGE execd. When I run `uname -m` at the command line, I get what I'd expect: `x86_64`. But when I run `uname -m` inside an SGE script on the same host, the output is `i686`. This breaks anything which depends on a correct reading from `uname -m`.

I can workaround the problem, so my question is more academic than practical. I downloaded the uname source code but I couldn't find where it was pulling machine architecture data from. I assume this problem comes about because `uname -m` is run by a 32-bit parent process instead of a 64-bit parent process. So my question is - is that assumption correct, and if so, why is uname influenced by the architecture of the process which executes it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uname -m` is used to report the `personality(2)` of the 'virtual machine' running the code. Because the kernel can run code with different personalities (say, 32-bit code on a 64-bit machine, complete with 'only' a 32-bit address space, or short inodes, different signal numbers, or similar constraints), programs might use the output of `uname -m` to determine how they should run -- i.e., which kernel interfaces they will get at runtime.

So it is important that `uname -m` reflect the *personality*, not the full extent of the hardware.

Perhaps you can insert a call to `setarch(8)` or `personality(2)` into your software before the `fork(2)` `exec()` of your `uname -m` command and subsequent helper programs.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that Linux supported "multi-arch" in this way. So SGE must be calling one of these methods for consistency.

At least on my system, `linux64` is a convenient shortcut to `setarch(8)`